# Comparing outputs in python

Tags: python

Below is simplified example of a larger program i'm working on that is meant to create a single number from some inputs and then compare the two numbers, by saying which one is bigger. In this case is a computer and all its parts have a number and all those numbers added together form an overall number that I want to used to compare computers. Can someone suggest what would be the best method to do this?

```
class compcomputer:

    def __init__(self,cpu,ram,graph):
        self.cpu = cpu
        self.ram = ram
        self.graph = graph

    def __int__(self, other):
        number = (int(0.4*self.cpu) + 0.2*int(self.ram) + 0.2*int(self.graph))
        return number

computer1 = compcomputer(2,3,1)
computer2 = compcomputer(7,3,3)
```

I am looking for a way to compare the resulting numbers of computer1 and computer2 to tell which is bigger.Sorry for the noob question as I'm sure there is a simple solution i'm overlooking. Thank you in advance for your guidance.

Comment: What do you mean about comparing? Why not using c1 > c2?

Comment: I am trying to ding a way to so "computer2  is larger than computer1" by running their input through the equation in def__int__ to get a resulting number for each.

Comment: You cannot compare a two instances of a class, inside of the class definition itself. You will need to do a simple comparison outside of the `__init__` method, as proposed by @mohammad.

Comment: so do you mean something along the lines of............                                         
if (computer1 > computer2):
    print("computer1 is greater")
else:
    print("computer2 is greater")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend adding a **gt** and **lt** method to your class that operates on an instance variable that you generate. Like this:

```
class CompComputer:

    def __init__(self,cpu,ram,graph):
        self.cpu = cpu
        self.ram = ram
        self.graph = graph
        self.score = self.generate_score()

    def generate_score(self):
        number = (int(0.4  *self.cpu) + 0.2 * int(self.ram) + 0.2 * int(self.graph))
        return number

    def __gt__(self, other):
        return self.score > other.score

    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self.score < other.score

computer1 = CompComputer(2,3,1)
computer2 = CompComputer(7,3,3)

print(computer1 > computer2)
print(computer1 < computer2)
```

You can read about these methods here: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html